# Getting location using another class not working when calling function swift

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location

I was using the **ViewController** class before to get the users updates but now when expanding the application i needed to move it to another class that simply handles all the location updates. Here is the code that i am using now:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBAction func pickMeUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        sendPushNotificationController().sendPushNotification("sendRequest",userLat: defaults.stringForKey("userLat")!, userLong: defaults.stringForKey("userLong")! )
    }

    @IBOutlet var numberForPickup: UITextField!

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.numberForPickup.delegate = self

        getLocationController().initLocation()
    }
```

So i made another class called **getLocationController** with an init function that should start the location updates. Here is the code:

```
class getLocationController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func initLocation(){

    print("Im in here")

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {

    print("In location")

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active {

        print("App in Foreground")

    }else {

        let Device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
        let iosVersion = Double(Device.systemVersion) ?? 0

        let iOS9 = iosVersion >= 9
        if iOS9{
            locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
            locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
        }
        //let iOS7 = iosVersion >= 7 && iosVersion < 8
        print("App is backgrounded. New location is %@", newLocation)
    }
}
}
```

Now the print in initLocation is printed but not the print in didUpdateLocations. I used the very same code in **ViewController** class and it worked perfectly fine. Now when i am trying to move it to another class that is now really a view on the phone but simply a helper class its not working. Any ideas why?

Comment: Could it be that i never instantiate the getLocationController and that means that the var that i create at the top does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you assigning the getLocationController to a variable anywhere in the ViewController. That means the getLocationController would go out of scope and be destroyed, wouldn't it? That would explain why the callback didUpdateToLocation  isn't called.

Try:

```
class ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBAction func pickMeUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    sendPushNotificationController().sendPushNotification("sendRequest",userLat: defaults.stringForKey("userLat")!, userLong: defaults.stringForKey("userLong")! )
}

@IBOutlet var numberForPickup: UITextField!

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var glc:getLocationController // is this how it is in Swift?!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.numberForPickup.delegate = self

    glc = getLocationController()
    glc.initLocation()
}
```

Comment: So i added let locationController = getLocationController() to my viewcontroller class. And then i call it like this locationController.initLocation(). I am guessing that is what you meant? Still not working if so

Comment: Do you have didFailWithError in your code? You did not write it in the above example.

Comment: Also, why are you inheriting from UIVC? A helper class shouldn't inherit.

Comment: Alright it works fine now. I made it so it inherits from NSObject instead so its not a viewController anymore. I also added failed with error thank you. I will give the bounty in 7 hours as i have to wait that long